# getting an attribute from a list of elements in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have an example like this:

```
listing = {
    "ret_code": 0,
    "ret_msg": "ok",
    "ext_code": "",
    "result": {
        "pages": 10,
        "data": [                <--- would like to get ALL information under "data"
            {
                "user_id": 1,
                "qty": 2,
                "order_status": "Filled",
                "ext_fields": {
                    "close_on_trigger": true,
                    "orig_order_type": "BLimit",
                    "o_req_num": -34799032763,
                    "xreq_type": "x_create"
                },
                "last_exec_price": 7070.5,
                "leaves_qty": 0,
             ]
[... snip ...]
}
```

Please note: the ~full text~ being worked with is on the "Response" structure on this page: https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/inverse/#t-getactive

What I would like to do is get the information under the "data" attribute (i.e. something like listing["data"]). I would like to get back everything under the "data" attribute.

How can this be done?

**ETA: I have tried:**

```
 data =  [item for item in listing if item.attribute == 'data']
```

**But my result was as follows:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../trade_bybit/trade_bybit.py", line 198, in get_recent_orders
    data =  [item for item in listing if item.attribute == 'data']
  File "../trade_bybit/trade_bybit.py", line 198, in <listcomp>
    data =  [item for item in listing if item.attribute == 'data']
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'attribute'
```

**ETA:** @Joshua Varghese
Thanks for the hint. I tried

```
[item for item in listing if item == 'data']
```

but the answer I got was:

```
[]
```

Comment: Why use `item.attribute` when you can do `[item for item in listing if item == 'data']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `"data"` is a key in the dictionary corresponding to the key  `"results"`.
So therefore, use:

```
[listing["results"][item] for item in listing["results"] if item == 'data']
```

or just:

```
[value for key,value in listing["results"].items() if key == 'data']
```

---

If the entire structure contains only one `"data"`, yes, you can use:

```
data = listing[0]['result']['data']
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint :)  What really did it for me was:  data = listing[0]['result']['data']  - it exactly got the data needed. I snipped off some pieces (to make the post smaller) but I will put in a full example of what was being "worked on"